# Xcode Cocos-2dx Library Not Found Error

Tags: xcode5, cocos2d-x

I archived the cocos-2dx project and opened it in other folder but got this linking error.

> ld: library not found for -lwebsockets
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I think that this error is just because of xcode configuration. Please guide me how I resolve this error. 
I nothing changed anything in my projects settings.


I am using xcode5.

Thanks

Comment: What version of cocos2d-x?

Comment: check that websockets library is built with all supported architectures, ie if it doesn't include arm64 but your app does, this error will occur.

Comment: i solved this issue by delete this library from libs folder

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I was cloning a repo to a new computer and received the same error message.  To fix this issue, go to Project -> Build Settings -> Search Paths...change the Library Search Paths from absolute to relative paths.

Here is what I had to change to make it work.
[image]

Hope this helps - Scott